# What level of interrogation should I use in the Hinkley Point case?

Tags: floor-13

When I'm interrogating the second terrorist, what level of interrogation should I use to extract information from him?

[This](https://strategywiki.org/wiki/Floor_13/Walkthrough#Hinkley_Point) walk-thru doesn't give much information about it.